# Text analysis in python

Tags: python, text

Have you seen some good tutorials for text analysis in python or just as a theory? I mean something like determining the topic of a text, analyzing words etc.

Comment: There are a number of good examples of natural language processing and other text mining techniques out there - search for them and then ask your specific questions when you have trouble. As it stands, this question is far too opinion based.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/), it comes with four supported languages (Java, Scala, **Python** and R), it's compatible with `ipython` and `jupyter` with some tricky [modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064031/link-spark-with-ipython-notebook/33065359#33065359).

There some courses you can audit:

- [Introduction to Big Data](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x)
- [Scalable Machine Learning](https://www.edx.org/course/scalable-machine-learning-uc-berkeleyx-cs190-1x)

Here is a small pdf that paves the subject.

- [Text Analysis with Apache Spark](http://www.textanalyticsworld.com/pdf/SF/2015/Day1_1405_Daniel.pdf)

And here I show a small example of `word-count` using `Apache-Spark`, but it is not limited to this subject (it has `PCA`, `SVD`, and a big etc.)

```
documentRDD = sc.parallelize(["Hello", "world", "from", "the", "python", "world"])
tokensTupleRDD = documentRDD.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
tokensCountRDD = tokensTupleRDD.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
print(tokensCountRDD.collect()) 
# ("Hello", 1), ("world", 2),...
```

Other alternative is to use [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/), which is very used, easy and covers this area too, the only bad thing is that algorithms can't run in clusters and don't scale nicely.

They even have a very easy tutorial in their site:

- [Scikit-learn Tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html)

So if your trying to learn I would suggest `scikit-learn`, but if you are trying to apply `Bid Data` at your work I might suggest you to study both and use `Apache Spark`