# Unable to launch iPython notebook for Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I have Apache Spark installed in Ubuntu and I recently installed IPython notebook. It was all running fine until I restarted my laptop and now when I run with following command:

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
```

it tries to search wrong path for Java and gives following error:

```
/home/username/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-class: line 77: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
```

Obviously it is looking for wrong JAVA home path since it has extra "/bin/java" appended to it. Echoing JAVA_HOME gives correct path:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Help me resolve this.

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly, it should stop at the root of the java installation which is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre`. If you have `java_home` (e.g. `/usr/libexec/java_home`) you can do `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` to set `$JAVA_HOME` correctly.

Comment: Thanks. After following steps in this post, it worked. Actually it should be just "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64".http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users

Comment: Try this [Installing Jupyter for Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064031/link-spark-with-ipython-notebook/33065359#33065359)