# Create pyspark kernel for Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, jupyter

I was looking at Apache Toree to use as Pyspark kernel for Jupyter

https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree

However it was using older version of Spark (1.5.1 vs current 1.6.0). I tried to use this method here http://arnesund.com/2015/09/21/spark-cluster-on-openstack-with-multi-user-jupyter-notebook/ by creating `kernel.js`

```
{
 "display_name": "PySpark",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local[*] pyspark-shell"
 }
}
```

However, I got few problems:

1. There is no `/jupyter/kernels` path in my Mac. So I ended up creating this path `~/.jupyter/kernels/pyspark`. I am not sure if that is the correct path.
2. Even after having all correct paths, I still don't see `PySpark` showing up as a kernel inside Jupyter.

What did I miss?

Comment: Read this [Jupyter for Pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064031/link-spark-with-ipython-notebook/33065359#33065359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter kernels should go in $JUPYTER_DATA_DIR. On OSX, this is ~/Library/Jupyter. See: http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/system.html

Comment: It's weird that Jupyter decided to put a folder somewhere else outside of my current notebook repo which I built.

Comment: Dead `404` link, also, possibly out of date info. Currently, see http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html , which suggests it could be now `$JUPYTER_PATH`, though the aforementioned "data dir" env var may still be respected. To query where that directory is on your system, run `jupyter --data-dir`

Answer (score 22):

launch jupyter notebook with python kernel and then run the following commands to initialize pyspark within Jupyter.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```

FYI: have tried most of the configs to launch Apache Toree with pyspark kernel in Jupyter without success,

Comment: The findspark library depends on the SPARK_HOME environment variable -- I hadn't set that up yet, so I had to do (in the terminal) `export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark`

Comment: Important note - if you're trying to connect to a cluster (not run locally) make sure to include the following arguments:
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName=app_name, master=spark://IP:PORT) It took me a lot of googling to figure out why there weren't any applications showing up on my cluster dashboard

Comment: if your jupyter kernel is configured correctly for pyspark, the spark context will be defined for you.  But if your kernel is configured correctly, you don't need `findspark` :-)