# Spark submit - Input_raw python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

i want test my model with a input values.
So, my script  is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import csv
import sys
import os
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, LogisticRegressionWithSGD

APP_NAME = 'Predictive Example'
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
conf = conf.setMaster('spark://james-VirtualBox:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

myModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc, "examples/src/main/python/Prudential/Model_Prudential_Classi")

rint (" The variavel is")
userinput = stdin.readline()
var1 = raw_input("Insert Insurance variable ")
var2 = raw_input("Insert Medical Variable ")
# 10 variables for testing model
print (" The variavel is",var1)
```

but when the i insert de value the console don´t continue.. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use ipython notebooks [how to link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064031/link-spark-with-ipython-notebook/33065359#33065359)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532465/function-input-in-pyspark