# Function input() in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My problem here is when I enter the value of p, Nothing happens, It does not pursue execution: is there a way to fix it please?

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "simple App") 

p =input("Enter the word")
rdd1 = sc.textFile("monfichier") 
rdd2= rdd1.map(lambda l : l.split("\t")) 
rdd3=rdd2.map(lambda l: l[1])  
print rdd3.take(6)
rdd5=rdd3.filter(lambda l : p in l)

sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to distinguish between to different cases:

- Script submitted with `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit script.py`

  In this case you execute Scala application which in turn starts Python interpreter. Since Scala application doesn't expect any interaction from  the standard input, not to mention passing it to Python interpreter, your Python script will simply hang waiting for data which won't come.
- Script executed directly using Python interpreter (`python script.py`).

  You should be able to use `input` directly but at the cost of handling all the configuration details, normally handled by `spark-submit` / `org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit`, manually in your code.

In general all required arguments for your scripts can be passed using commandline

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit script.py some_app_arg another_app_arg
```

and accessed using standard methods like [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv) or [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and using `input` is neither necessary nor useful.

Comment: If you want interactive input from user then you still need to find a way to input data at runtime

Answer (score 4):

You can use `py4j` to get input via Java

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

scanner = sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Scanner  
sys_in = getattr(sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.System, 'in')  
result = scanner(sys_in).nextLine()  
print(result)
```

Depending on your environment/spark version you might need to replace `sc` with `spark.sparkContext`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in Azure DataBricks, I used widgets to get input from the user.