# Pyspark command not recognised

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have anaconda installed and also I have downloaded Spark 1.6.2. I am using the following instructions from this answer to configure spark for Jupyter [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064031/link-spark-with-ipython-notebook)

I have downloaded and unzipped the spark directory as

```
~/spark
```

Now when I cd into this directory and into bin I see the following

```
SFOM00618927A:spark $ cd bin
SFOM00618927A:bin $ ls
beeline         pyspark         run-example.cmd     spark-class2.cmd    spark-sql       sparkR
beeline.cmd     pyspark.cmd     run-example2.cmd    spark-shell     spark-submit        sparkR.cmd
load-spark-env.cmd  pyspark2.cmd        spark-class     spark-shell.cmd     spark-submit.cmd    sparkR2.cmd
load-spark-env.sh   run-example     spark-class.cmd     spark-shell2.cmd    spark-submit2.cmd
```

I have also added the environment variables as mentioned in the above answer to my .bash_profile and .profile

Now in the spark/bin directory first thing I want to check is if pyspark command works on shell first.

So I do this after doing cd spark/bin

```
SFOM00618927A:bin $ pyspark
-bash: pyspark: command not found
```

As per the answer after following all the steps I can just do

```
pyspark
```

in terminal in any directory and it should start a jupyter notebook with spark engine. But even the pyspark within the shell is not working forget about making it run on juypter notebook

Please advise what is going wrong here.

Edit:

I did

```
open .profile
```

at home directory and this is what is stored in the path.

```
export PATH=/Users/854319/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/854319/spark/bin
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' pyspark
```

Comment: Did you follow step 8 of the answer? Adding the bin folder to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: After doing cd spark/bin, $ ./pyspark will work, did u tried this

Comment: @rfkortekaas Yes i followed step 8 of the answer. I have all those in the path still its not working

Comment: Can you add the contents of PATH：'echo $PATH'

Comment: @rfkortekaas Hi check below

/Users/i854319/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Also I tried SANDHYALALKUMAR answer. It gave an error: No Java Runtime Installed even though I have installed it. Do i need to restart the computer to make it effective?

Comment: @rfkortekaas check Edit. I added the contents of .profile file

Comment: @rfkortekaas ok i set JDK up and now when I just do pyspark it opens up a jupyter notebook. I dont have to do ./pyspark.. Last thing- what if I just want to open the pyspark on console instead of opening a notebook. What command do we type then?

Answer (score 4):

1- You need to set `JAVA_HOME` and spark paths for the shell to find them. After setting them in your `.profile` you may want to

```
source ~/.profile
```

to activate the setting in the current session. From your comment I can see you're already having the `JAVA_HOME` issue.

Note if you have `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login`, `.profile` will not work as described [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)

2- When you are in `spark/bin` you need to run

```
./pyspark
```

to tell the shell that the target is in the current folder.

Comment: ok i set this up and now when I just do pyspark it opens up a jupyter notebook. I dont have to do ./pyspark.. Last thing- what if I just want to open the pyspark on console instead of opening a notebook. What command do we type then?

Comment: You need to clear the settings of `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my environment vars, hope it will help you:

```
# path to JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

#Spark
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark" #version 1.6
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

^^ Remove the Pyspark_driver_python_opts option if you don't want the notebook to launch, otherwise you can leave this out entirely and use it on your command line when you need it.

I have anaconda vars in another line to append to the PATH.

Comment: Helped particular string `export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark" #version 1.6 `, however I've downloaded the source itself: `/Users/iamtodor/programming/tools/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who came here during or after MacOS Catalina, make sure you're establishing/sourcing variables in **zshrc** and not **bash**.

`$ nano ~/.zshrc`

```
# Set Spark Path
export SPARK_HOME="YOUR_PATH/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Set pyspark + jupyter commands
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="pyspark-shell"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='lab' pyspark
```

`$ source ~/.zshrc`

`$ pyspark` # Automatically opens Jupyter Lab w/ PySpark initialized.