# Unable to start spark-shell failing to submit spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to submit spark-submit but its failing with as weird message.

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
```

this is the first time I am seeing this kind of error. I tried to check the code for the spark-class file but unable to decipher what is causing the issue.

```sh
# Turn off posix mode since it does not allow process substitution
set +o posix
CMD=()
DELIM=$'\n'
CMD_START_FLAG="false"
while IFS= read -d "$DELIM" -r ARG; do
  if [ "$CMD_START_FLAG" == "true" ]; then
    CMD+=("$ARG")
  else
    if [ "$ARG" == $'\0' ]; then
      # After NULL character is consumed, change the delimiter and consume command string.
      DELIM=''
      CMD_START_FLAG="true"
    elif [ "$ARG" != "" ]; then
      echo "$ARG"
    fi
  fi
done < <(build_command "$@")

COUNT=${#CMD[@]}
LAST=$((COUNT - 1))
LAUNCHER_EXIT_CODE=${CMD[$LAST]}
```

the line which is mentioned in the error message is

```sh
LAUNCHER_EXIT_CODE=${CMD[$LAST]}
```

Any pointer or any idea why the issue will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: @hatefAlipoor yeah I was able to solve the issue by providing an entry point for the code to start

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "providing an entry point for the code to start"? I seeing the same problem. This is what I'm seeing in my terminal:
"$ pyspark
set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && python
C:\Users\oefel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript"
Is this what you were seeing?

Comment: @Erin can you provide a brief description what you are trying to do ? Looks like you are simply submitting a spark-submit job in a windows machine. Can you ensure the spark required paths are set. Mine error was in different context it was from a pod in which I was trying to execute my job.

Comment: I'm looking to correctly set up the SPARK_HOME env variable so as to use pyspark within a Jupyter Notebook. I've set env variables by Max' comment in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798816/pyspark-command-not-recognised . I'm now seeing:
"/c/spark/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark: line 24: C:spark\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/c/spark/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark: line 77: C:spark\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory"

Comment: I am getting this simply by trying to run the pyspark shell in the terminal. Any thoughts? It looks like I'm trying to do something similar to what Erin is doing.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue while trying to run pyspark in a cygwin enviroment.  My environment variables are:

export SPARK_PYTHON=python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
export SPARK_HOME='c:/spark/spark-3.1.2'
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME='c:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_301'

I get the following output:

set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && python
c:/spark/spark-3.1.2/bin/spark-class: line 98: CMD: bad array subscript

Answer (score 0):

When I faced exactly the same problem, I looked in a bin directory of my Spark setup which is in your Windows PATH variable and when you run `spark-submit <arguments>` CMD searches for this command in Spark's bin. This directory can be found by executing `echo %SPARK_HOME%\bin` in CMD. And I saw two copies for every executable [bin directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAOQq.png). This makes sense because we need different executable scripts for Windows and Linux. **So finally I just typed `spark-submit.cmd` instead of `spark-submit` and everything worked like expected.**

Answer (score 0):

`TLDR`: the bash scripts provided with spark aren't designed to work in `cygwin` or `msys2` shell environments on a Windows system.   You should use the comparable `.cmd` scripts.

The error message you cite happens because the `build_command` function (defined in script `spark-class`) doesn't behave as the `spark-class` script expects it to on a `Windows` system.   The `build_command` function calls `org.apache.spark.launcher.Main` for the purpose of generating the appropriate launch command line, and the `spark-class` script `while` loop expects `NULLs` to appear between the command line entries.  However, on a Windows system, the `NULLs` are missing.

According the comment on lines 44-50 in the file `https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/Main.java`:

```
   * This class works in tandem with the "bin/spark-class" script on Unix-like systems, and
   * "bin/spark-class2.cmd" batch script on Windows to execute the final command.
   * <p>
   * On Unix-like systems, the output is a list of command arguments, separated by the NULL
   * character. On Windows, the output is a command line suitable for direct execution from the
   * script.
   */
```

Because of this, the `while` loop misfires, resulting in the error message you saw.

This problem doesn't happen when you run the `.cmd` scripts designed for Windows, although to do so from a bash shell, you might need to make them executable, like so:

`$ chmod +x $SPARK_HOME/bin/ -R`

Then, assuming `$SPARK_HOME/bin` is in your `PATH`, you can (for example) start a REPL session like this:

`$ spark-shell.cmd`

And similarly for the other bash scripts, use the `.cmd` alternative.

`$ spark-submit <args>`